# Solr query, filter query on parent and filter query on child

Tags: solr

Trying to understand if what I want is possible in Solr and if so how. From what I understand we can search for parent documents by text using the q parameter then we can filter those results further by using the fq parameter. Is there a way to filter it further based on criteria of all of its children? Essentially a q and fq parameter for children. For example, lets say I have the following parent and child documents:

```
{
     'content_type': 'parentDocument',
     'id': '1',
     'author': 'Stephen King',
     'active': true,
     '_childDocuments_': [
          {'id': 'child_1',
          'notes': 'may be late'
          'tour_dates': '[2023-09-16T00:00:00Z TO 2023-09-29T23:59:59Z]'
          }
     ]
}
```

If I wanted to search for authors having 'king' in their name and are still active I would do something like this:

> http://localhost:8983/solr/core/select?omitHeader=true&wt=json&fl=id%2Cauthor%2Cactive&q.op=OR&q=author%3Aking&fq=active%3Atrue

Now what I want to do is add another filter to only return parents that match the above criteria AND have at least one child where today/now is within the tour_dates and notes has the word 'late'. Is that possible? If so what would the query look like?

I got as far as: `q=+author:king +{!parent which='content_type:parentDocument'}notes:late +tour_dates:NOW &fq=active:true`, but it gives 0 results.